# How to impute using simple imputer (custom function)

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, training, data-imputation

I am imputing my data using simple imputer from sklearn. i want to test many different ways of applying transformations to the data. i.e for logisitcic regression i would like to

- remove nans and replace with mode
- replace +infs with max and -infs with min
- use standard scaler.

then for using xgboost i would like to:

- simply replace -infs/+infs with very large or -ve large numbers.

i have been playing with sklearn pipeline and i would like to know how i can pass the custom imputers through the pipeline? e.g:

```
logistic_pipeline = Pipeline( steps = [('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most frequent') ),
                                  ( 'std_scaler', StandardScaler() ),
                        ( 'model', LinearRegression() )] )
```

but how do i incorprate the following function into it where i am replacing infs from the training datase (df) with the max of that column . then using this max to populate it into the test.. how can i do this using pipeline?

```
def replace_pos_inf(df, dftest, numeric_features):

    for col in df[numeric_features].columns:
        m = df.loc[df[col] != np.inf, col].max()
        df[col].replace(np.inf,m,inplace=True)
        dftest[col].replace(np.inf,m,inplace=True)


    for col in df[numeric_features].columns:
        mini = df.loc[df[col] != -np.inf, col].min()
        df[col].replace(-np.inf,mini,inplace=True)
        dftest[col].replace(-np.inf,mini,inplace=True)

    return df,dftest
```

Comment: Are you only trying to impute? Or is this a preprocessing step? You can explore pipelines if you don't want to transform your data in between steps.

Comment: no i'm trying to impute and standardize, but it seems like when i use standard scaler it converts my dataframe to array so i lose all indexs, therfore when i train how can i know that the x indices correspind to the y;s

Comment: @Neels have changed question since  resolved what wa going on before

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to save the training min/max and use those to replace inf's in the test set, you need a [custom transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html).  To build a robust transformer, you should use some of sklearn's validation functions.  And it's best to work in numpy, since as you point out an earlier transformer in a pipeline will have already converted an input dataframe to an nparray.  (You *could* stick with dataframes, and either convert in your transformer (losing some efficiency), or make sure your transformer always comes first in a pipeline (alright if you're the only one using your code).)

Then, here's a simple version.  I'm opting not to have the `numeric_features` as input; you're probably better off using a `ColumnTransformer` to do that kind of selection for you.

```py
from sklearn.utils import check_array
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator

class ReplaceInf(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    '''Replace +-np.inf with the max/min finite values in each column.
    Attributes
    ----------
    mins_ : np.ndarray
        Per-column minimum finite values.
    maxs_ : np.ndarray
        Per-column maximum finite values.
    '''

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # validate and convert if possible:
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite=False)
        # using `where=np.isfinite(X)`, nan's won't affect the min/max calculation,
        #  and using `clip` to transform will preserve nan's as well.
        self.mins_ = np.amin(X, axis=0, where=np.isfinite(X), initial=np.inf)
        self.maxs_ = np.amax(X, axis=0, where=np.isfinite(X), initial=-np.inf)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite=False)
        return np.clip(X, self.mins_, self.maxs_)
```